# Character pattern replacement using gsub, loops, and data.table

Tags: performance, r

I was trying to see if `data.table` could speed up a `gsub` pattern matching function over a list.

Data for reprex. It's a list of 3 data frames with some asterisks placed here and there. Each data frame is 6500 rows, 2 columns, and generally representative of my actual data. My data does have multiple columns per data frame that need to be looped over, which is why I'm using the `mapply`.

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
    df1 <- data.frame(name = rep(LETTERS, 250), code = rep(letters, 250), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1$name[df1$name == "D" | df1$name == "F" | df1$name == "L"] <- "foo*"
df1$code[df1$code == "d" | df1$code == "f" | df1$code == "l"] <- "*foo"
df2 <- data.frame(name = rep(LETTERS, 250), code = rep(letters, 250), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2$name[df2$name == "A" | df2$name == "R" | df2$name == "T"] <- "foo*"
df2$code[df2$code == "a" | df2$code == "r" | df2$code == "t"] <- "*foo*"
df3 <- data.frame(name = rep(LETTERS, 250), code = rep(letters, 250), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df3$name[df3$name == "C" | df3$name == "Q" | df3$name == "W"] <- "foo*"
df3$code[df3$code == "c" | df3$code == "q" | df3$code == "w"] <- "*f*oo"


df <- list(df1, df2, df3)
dt <- lapply(df, as.data.table)
```

In this example, I am trying to remove any `*` symbols from character strings. First function was just using an `mapply` and `gsub`. It deletes any `*`, looping over elements. Second was an attempt to do it using the `data.table` library.

```
mapply.remove.asterisk = function(x){
  df2 <- data.frame(mapply(gsub, "\\*", "", x, perl = TRUE))
  colnames(df2) <- colnames(x)
}

dt.remove.asterisk = function (x) {
  x[, lapply(.SD, function(x) gsub("\\*", "", x, perl = TRUE))]
}
```

Testing them out doesn't show a big difference, but the `mapply` is slightly slower.

```
mapgsubtest = function(x) {
  df.test <- lapply(x, mapply.remove.asterisk)
}

dtgsubtest = function(x) {
  dt.test <- lapply(x, dt.remove.asterisk)
}

microbenchmark(mapgsubtest(df), dtgsubtest(dt), neval = 100)

Unit: nanoseconds
            expr     min      lq       mean  median      uq      max neval
 mapgsubtest(df) 7161991 7388846 7780101.83 7483794 7651907 27860732   100
  dtgsubtest(dt) 6759663 6991926 7181127.95 7109710 7275418 10102686   100
           neval       0       0      12.26       0       1      902   100
```

Is there something I'm doing within `data.table` that could be improved? I tried to see if a few things sped everything up, like having `*` only at the end of strings (only `foo*`), using an end of string regex anchor `$`, and setting an index key. Nothing changed noticeably.

Comment: I'm curious why you need to make your code faster (6500 rows and your current computation times seem pretty small), could you elaborate? That being said, using  `gsub` with the `fixed = TRUE` option (for which the first argument should be changed to `"*"`) will give you that x10 improvement you are probably after. Also note that when using `microbenchmark`, you should be using `times = 100` rather than `neval = 100`.

Comment: I just chose that to primarily be representative for the pattern matching problem. My working datasets are larger, but I didn't want to post an example on the order of MBs, so I kept it smallish.  You are correct, using `fixed` vs `perl` did speed things up. Thank you for that suggestion. This is just part of some code maintenance I'm working on, and one of the bigger bottlenecks, apart from the LaTeX. It initially lacked the `perl = T`, which sped it up, so I was curious if `data.table` could improve it at all.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason that you are using `mapply` to gsub through the number columns as well? You can just replace in the first column if that is all you need, which gets some speed improvement, about 2x on my machine. I also tried using `stringi` instead of gsub but it was not faster. This is also a speedup on the order of milliseconds though!

```r
library(data.table)
#> Warning: package 'data.table' was built under R version 3.5.1
library(microbenchmark)
#> Warning: package 'microbenchmark' was built under R version 3.5.1
library(stringi)
df1 <- data.frame(name = rep(LETTERS, 250), number = rep(c(1:26), 250), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1$name[df1$name == "D" | df1$name == "F" | df1$name == "L"] <- "foo*"
df2 <- data.frame(name = rep(LETTERS, 250), number = rep(c(1:26), 250), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2$name[df2$name == "A" | df2$name == "R" | df2$name == "T"] <- "*foo*"
df3 <- data.frame(name = rep(LETTERS, 250), number = rep(c(1:26), 250), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df3$name[df3$name == "C" | df3$name == "Q" | df3$name == "W"] <- "f*oo"

df <- list(df1, df2, df3)
dt <- lapply(df, as.data.table)

mapply.remove.asterisk = function(x){
  df2 <- data.frame(mapply(gsub, "\\*", "", x, perl = TRUE))
  colnames(df2) <- colnames(x)
}

dt.remove.asterisk = function (x) {
  x[, lapply(.SD, function(x) gsub("\\*", "", x, perl = TRUE))]
}

stringi.remove.asterisk = function (x) {
  out <- x
  out$name <- stri_replace_all_regex(x$name, "\\*", "")
  out
}

gsub.remove.asterisk = function(x) {
  out <- x
  out$name <- gsub("\\*", "", x$name)
  out
}

mapgsubtest = function(x) {
  df.test <- lapply(x, mapply.remove.asterisk)
}

dtgsubtest = function(x) {
  dt.test <- lapply(x, dt.remove.asterisk)
}

strisubtest = function(x) {
  str.test <- lapply(x, stringi.remove.asterisk)
}

gsubtest = function(x){
  gsub.test <- lapply(x, gsub.remove.asterisk)
}

microbenchmark(mapgsubtest(df), dtgsubtest(dt), strisubtest(df), gsubtest(df))
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>             expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max
#>  mapgsubtest(df) 8.031179 8.789332 9.429985 9.164945 9.740215 12.913776
#>   dtgsubtest(dt) 7.276307 7.867076 8.553440 8.217892 8.855339 22.473660
#>  strisubtest(df) 8.149333 8.745572 9.391304 9.221469 9.846153 13.492875
#>     gsubtest(df) 4.153983 4.667258 5.053101 4.789789 5.231771  9.813332
#>  neval
#>    100
#>    100
#>    100
#>    100
```

Created on 2018-10-20 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using `mapply` because I have multiple columns per data frame where I'm removing the `*`.

Comment: You might wish to include that in your sample data, because it becomes important if you are trying to profile for speed

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have revised my example data to reflect that.